# Using a specific flatpage in a template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-1.7

I'm using [django flatpage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/flatpages/#module-django.contrib.flatpages)s, and I'm wondering if there is a concise way of loading one specific flatpage within a template. The docs show the following patterns:

```
{% load flatpages %}

{% get_flatpages '/about/' as about_pages %}
{% get_flatpages about_prefix as about_pages %}
{% get_flatpages '/about/' for someuser as about_pages %}
```

I just want to load one specific page in a template, essentially using it like an include statement (e.g. `{% include 'homepage.html' %}`)

The approach I am using is this:

```
{% get_flatpages '/flat-homepage/' as flatpages %}
{{ flatpages.first.content|safe }}
```

This works fine, but I thought there might be a slightly neater way of doing this. I'm marking the content as `safe` as I want html styles to be applied (again, not sure if there is a better way of doing this)

Comment: Are you trying to access that content outside of desired flatpage?

Answer (score 2):

By default, there are 2 solutions for that.

First, register your flatpage in urls as below:

```
from django.contrib.flatpages import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about-us/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/about-us/'}, name='about'),
]
```

That way, you can access it using `{% url %}` tag, like normal view.

Second way, if you know exact url of that page, you can access it's url using:

```
{% url 'django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage' url='url_to_flatpage_here' %}
```

There is no other way, because all flatpages are identified by url.

Comment: I tried with URL name and it worked: {% url 'about' %}